# Are linqtosql objects serializable?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, linq-to-sql, serialization

Hi I am developing a webservice via asp.net 3.5 , I wonder if I use lintosql as ORM then different datatypes that I use to return (datatable,object,List,class members, etc) would be serializable by default  ? or I need to modify linqtosql classes to make them serializable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by setting the Serialization Mode property to `Unidirectional`. I would however recommend that you create your own DTO's and expose those in your webservice instead of auto generated linq entities. It'll give greater control over you API.

For more information on the subject: [LINQ to SQL serialization capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546184.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer ! and Is it better to use ADO.NET insted of linqtosql ? That way I simply creat a datatable in my webmethods and return them and asp.net will take care of serialization . Is It better ?